# How can I make Windows believe a debugger is present for my own process?

Tags: c++, windows, debugging, winapi, process

I want the 'BeingDebugged' field in the PEB for my process to always be true. I'm not interested in actually debugging the process, I just want Windows to believe it is being debugged. The process is usermode, so I don't have any ability to change BeingDebugged directly.

I want Windows to think there's a debugger and set the BeingDebugged to true itself, without me needing to try forcibly set it to true with some hack.

I'm not sure what criteria Windows uses to determine if a process is being debugged or not.

I've tried: `DebugActiveProcess(GetCurrentProcessId());` and other Windows debug API functions but couldn't get this to work, I have been verifying whether or not my solutions have worked with calls to `IsDebuggerPresent()`. In the case where it works correctly, this function would always return true for the process. Hooking `IsDebuggerPresent();` to make it return true wont suffice, I need Windows itself to believe it's being debugged.

I am thinking that adding hardware breakpoints to unreachable parts of the code may also cause Windows to believe there is a debugger present, but I haven't tried it as this seems a complex route to try before first asking if there is a more obvious way.

I think the ideal solution would be to know exact what the criteria is for Windows to set BeingDebugged to true, and recreate this within the program. Lastly, I am thinking if there's no obvious way to do this, I could bundle a lightweight debugger and actually debug the process.

The program is in C++, but I would be interested in any solution.

Comment: You can absolutely modify the BeingDebugged field yourself (from usermode and the process itself).

Comment: DebugActiveProcess will always return ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED if the PID of the current process == the passed in dwProcessId.

Comment: "*I'm not interested in actually debugging the process, I just want Windows to believe it is being debugged.*" - Why? What issue are you trying to solve by doing this? In any case, I would simply create a separate process to use the debug API on the target process. The target process could spawn that debugger process at startup if no debugger is already present (ie, when running the target process from an IDE). All of the code can be implemented in a single exe, where the target process spawns another instance of itself passing its current PID as a command-line parameter.

Comment: @joshpoley I didn't think I could modify that field myself, I guess it would be complex? Can't find too much on it, but maybe I'm looking in the wrong places. I am worried that Windows might set that value back to false if I switched it manually anyway, I'd rather that Windows was the one to believe a debugger was present and changed the value itself so that it wouldn't be switching it back.

Comment: @afar, go with Remy's approach for the officially supported approach. But for completeness, this is all you need to modify the peb: `#include <winternl.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ntdll.lib")
extern "C" PPEB WINAPI RtlGetCurrentPeb();
PPEB pPeb = RtlGetCurrentPeb();
pPeb->BeingDebugged = TRUE;`

Comment: @joshpoley - of course very easy set `pPeb->BeingDebugged = TRUE;`, but this is senseless. unclear for what OP want this trick. possible as anti-debug trick. for this not enouth modify PEB in user mode. but anyway, debugger can remove existing debug object, and attach self.

Comment: @RbMm Not intended as an anti-debug trick or otherwise. It was desired to exactly recreate functionality as it appeared when debugging through the IDE, but when built as an executable. My issue was that I was experiencing different behaviors while application was being debugged and while it wasn't. Directly changing "BeingDebugged" did work to change that flag, but still the functionality was different unfortunately. Only thing that has worked is the spawning a separate process approach suggested by Remy Lebeau.